# Where's the documentation for the JavadocTool programmatic interface?

Tags: javadoc

To be clear, I'm not talking about the output of `javadoc -help`; I'm interested in using the JavadocTool class from Java code.

According to the [Javadoc FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#sourcecode), I should be able to find the source code (and hopefully the docs).  Unfortunately, that link points to the generic "Oracle acquired Sun" page.  I'm actually less interested in the source code than better documentation on the "JavadocTool" class as compared to what's provided by OpenJDK at docjar.com:

http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/tools/javadoc/JavadocTool.html

Specifically, I'd like to know more about the `getRootDocImpl` method.  **NOTE - I'm neither talking about the command line interface, nor the [Doclet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/index.html).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in large part, one can read the documentation for the command line tool and infer what `getRootDocImpl` is going to do with its arguments.  I say in large part because I initially tried passing options via `getRootDocImpl`'s "options" argument, but found that I needed to use a `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Options` object instead.

Further, Tobias Kortkamp was kind enough to have sent me an [example](http://in.relation.to/12969.lace).  There, you can see that use of `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Options` I referred to earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/index.html.  Seems to be a reasonable hub for javadoc stuff.

Comment: Yes, it does *seem* reasonable, but I'm looking for JavadocTool class documentation and not just for how to use `javadoc` the command line tool or how to document using tags.

Comment: Ah, that's somewhat clearer now you've rewritten the question :)